# mp4 video not playing in mobile

Tags: html, video

I have a video in my html page and its an auto play video. It works well on my laptop but not for mobile devices. It just displayed as an image! I found no solution for it!

```
<header>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <!--  muted="muted" loop="loop" -->
    <video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
        <source src="Whispers.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div class="container h-100">
        <div class="d-flex h-100 text-center align-items-center">
            <div class="w-100 text-white">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<section class="my-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 mx-auto">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: if you are acessing from Ios make sure you don't have energy-saving on. This makes it so the video won't play.

Comment: @ThiagoViana iOS or android both not working at all

Comment: Are you able to share a link to the video - it may be that the format has something that is not supported on mobile devices?

Comment: just as an FYI, attributes like autoplay or muted are binary ... the word is present then they are 'true', if it is not present then the value is 'false', so rather than use `muted="muted"` you might have more luck (if everything else is valid) using just `muted` etc